# Cannot reach docker container - port not bound

Tags: docker, networking, dockerfile

Setup first:

Windows 10 without WSL2 - old Hyper-V Backend

Docker for Windows - Linux containers.

I have a small python script:

```
from flask import Flask
server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route("/ping")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   server.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I run it locally (without docker) I can reach `localhost:5000/ping` just fine.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
USER user

WORKDIR /home/user

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm requirements.txt
COPY app.py .

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "app.py"]
```

Builds fine.
Start with: `docker container run -t test_tag -dp 5000:5000`
Log after start is also normal:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)

* Environment: production

WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.

Use a production WSGI server instead.

* Debug mode: off

* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But `localhost:5000/ping` does not work - connection failed.

But running the docker example `docker run -dp 80:80 docker/getting-started` works perfectly - I can access the webserver of the container under `localhost:80`

Running docker inspect on both containers shows one difference:
My container has

```
"Ports": {
                "5000/tcp": null
            },
```

in the network settings, for the working example it's (a more correct looking)

```
 "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

So it seems the required port is not bound correctly. What do I need to do to bind the port?

Comment: The `-d` and `-p` options need to appear _before_ the image name `test_tag`.  In the position they're in now they override the image's `CMD` instead of configuring Docker options.

Comment: Thanks! I just found this out seconds before your comment deeply burried in another stackoverflow answer... Man. Some big note for this in the docker getting started would be helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As David Maze pointed out, order does matter for the docker cmd command.

The `-dp` option needs to come before the image name.

So using

```
docker container run -dp 5000:5000 -t test_tag
```

works like a charm.

Comment: how can i set this on dockerfile?

Comment: Afaik, binding ports is not an option available in Dockerfiles (creating the container image), but it is always a runtime option when execution an image with docker or docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -dp 8080:8080 -it test_tag worked for me
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).